# point of intersection of a line l and the plane p, i get 0 somehow

Tags: vector-spaces

$L: x=\frac {y-1}{2}=\frac {z+1}{3}$,
$P= x − 2y + z = 1$.
Find the point of intersection of the line L and the
plane P.

Comment: i convert it to parametric equations but they end up gettin no answer for t, unless im doing it wrong

Comment: Have you tried directly substituting?

Comment: turns out the question changed and the acutally answer is that there exist no point of intersection between the line l and the plane p. thanks alot for looking into this for me anyway

Answer (score 1):

True, I tried directly substitution but I get a contradiction:

\begin{eqnarray}
-2x + y  &=& 1 \to y = 2x+1\\
 3x - z  &=& 1 \to z = 3x-1\\
 x-2y +z &=& 1 \\
 &\to& x-4x-2+3x-1 =1\\
 &\to& -2 = 2 ><
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: yh theres no answer but thanks alot for the help, ( i assumed there was an acutal answer until the changed the wording into if there exist a plane)

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: Are you dealing with one line or two lines, I do not understand the stament :

$$L:x = \frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z+1}{3}$$

Don't you mean :

\begin{eqnarray}
L_1 : x = \frac{y-1}{2} \\
L_2 : x = \frac{z+1}{3} 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: That is in fact one line; it is a system of equations whose solution set is a line. The L1 and L2 that you have pointed out are planes, not lines.